# Exorcising the ghost cursor of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I've encountered a strange issue in Windows 8 causing [a grayed out cursor to appear in the middle of one of my screens](http://youtu.be/2NFPs6k3ubY).
The cursor seems to be rendered, like with the proper curser, in front of all other windows yet translucent.

The problem seems to have appeared from out-of-nowhere, and I can't remember having encountered it before.
While I was working on a graphics application at the time, I hadn't made any additions to the code or modified the application in a way that should have induced any driver issues.
In fact, I was working in Emacs when the problem appeared; not running said graphics application.
This makes me believe that the issue could be an operating system bug, but I can't be sure - especially since I cannot find others having encountered the same issue.
As such, I'm unsure of whether or not to file a bug report.

**My question is as follows:**
Has anyone encountered similar issues, or know how I may get rid of ghost cursor haunting my primary screen?

Comment: Apparently you need a reputation of ten in order to post images. I'll attach an image of the issue as soon as I reach that reputation. Meanwhile, I linked a video showcasing the problem in the first paragraph.